# auth0 - invalid user_metadata.address type (only strings are allowed)

Tags: reactjs, auth0, auth0-js

I am using Auth0 for user management in my application. I am trying to signup by using this code:

```
signup({
  name: `${data.given_name} ${data.family_name}`,
  given_name: data.given_name,
  family_name: data.family_name,
  connection: AUTH0_CONNECTION,
  username: data.email,
  email: data.email,
  password: data.password,
  userMetadata: {
    accept_terms: data.accept_terms.toString(),
    job_title: data.job_title,
    certificate_image_id: data.certificate_image_id,
    company_name: data.company_name,
    phone_number: data.phone_number,
    certificate_image_url: data.certificate_image_url,
    website: data.website,
    address: {
      zipcode: data.zipcode,
      address1: data.address1,
      address2: data.address2,
      city: data.city,
      country: data.country,
      state: data.state,
    },
  },
})
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("You're successfully Registered!");
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("Error Occured!");
  })
  .finally();
```

In the roles of user MetaData of **Auth0**, there are not more than **10** fields. That is why I moved the address fields to another address object. But, it throws an error **invalid user_metadata.address type (only strings are allowed)**. I need all these fields.

Kindly help me to solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like auth0 only let's you have max of 10 string fields when using the sign up endpoint ([source](https://auth0.com/docs/manage-users/user-accounts/metadata/metadata-fields-data)). You can either stringify the address and store it in one string field or sign up the user and then add the address later on.